# Syntax Error when calling a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, php, function, parameters, syntax-error

When I click on a table cell, i want my program to run a function whilst passing the parameter `$venues[$y][1]` through. However, whenever i click on a cell, i get the error:

```
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '}'
```

Here is the function which gets called:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function displayPicture(x){
    alert(x);
}
</script>
```

Here is the line that calls the function (its html and php):

```
echo '<td class="venueNames" onclick="displayPicture("'.$venues[$y][1].'")">'.$venues[$y][1].'</td>';
```

For the sake of this example, lets assume `$venues[$y][1]` is Wembley.

Is the issue because I am passing a php variable as a parameter for a javascript function?

Comment: I have made some edits

Comment: "Is the issue because I am passing a php variable as a parameter for a javascript function?" — That isn't what you are doing. You are programmatically generating JavaScript embedded in HTML with PHP. Try looking at the source code that you are generating in your browser and seeing what you get. The error will likely become obvious.

Comment: *Danger*: Table cells are not designed to be interactive. They won't be announced as such by screen readers and they won't be accessible via the tab order for keyboard based navigation. This can make your site inaccessible to plenty of people. You should use a button instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have problably a problem with masking your quotation marks. Try the following:

```
echo '<td class="venueNames" onclick="displayPicture(\''.$venues[$y][1].'\')">'.$venues[$y][1].'</td>';
```

or

```
echo "<td class=\"venueNames\" onclick=\"displayPicture('{$venues[$y][1]}')\">{$venues[$y][1]}</td>";
```

In your original code the `onclick`-attribute will be seen by the browser as `onclick="displayPicture("` - i. e. the second double quotation mark is seen as the end of the onclick attribute and not as an internal quotation mark enclosing a string in your function call.

Comment: The second one should also work now. I forgot the curly braces before.